# How to handle the deeply nested json response of reddit apis in android?

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, reddit

I am trying to consume the Reddit API in android. I am currently using Retrofit with GSon.

One of the endpoints which I am dealing with has a very complex API response.

https://oauth.reddit.com/subreddits/popular

Here's what the API response looks like:
https://gist.github.com/roysailor/c991d8a854c064cbc48e2ee2d2ad2b69

I have tried creating a model class for it but it seems to be a very lengthy process.

Other options are using POJO generators or manual JSON Parsing.

What do you suggest is the best way to handle such a response?

Comment: You can create different pojo class as per json data

Comment: Won’t it result into too many wrapper classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "*the best way to handle this*" is opinion-based, but out of curiosity I copy-pasted your raw JSON into [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and it yielded 4 classes describing your data (so it's not that complex).

You could definitely import them in your codebase, since Reddit API is unlikely to change its model without warning you.

```
Child.java
Data.java // You should probably rename this
Data_.java // This aswell 
Example.java
```

Example.java :

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "kind",
    "data"
})
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("kind")
    private String kind;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Data data;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("kind")
    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    @JsonProperty("kind")
    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Feel free to fiddle around with the parameters to suit your codebase better.

Comment: Creating extra wrapper classes is what I am trying to avoid. Any ideas?

Comment: You just can't. Either you have these wrappers, or you create a single class with all subclasses in it. The latter will have several problems. First, it will be huge (like more than a thousand lines) and unmaintainable. Second, if you want to access a sub-element of the main response and handle it locally, you'll have to specify the enclosing class name (like `Response.SubClass`) absolutely everywhere. That will clutter your code. There's nothing wrong with creating subclasses. And most of the time, it makes everything easier

Answer (score 0):

Use `Gson` in conjunction with the POJO's created in Arthur's answer.

The best way to handle JSON is to identify the data structures within the JSON, create POJO's representing those structures, and then using GSON or another JSON serialization library to convert from POJO to JSON string and back.

https://github.com/google/gson